# Call an outer function that has the same name as an inner function

Tags: javascript

For the function doStuff below, is it possible to call sayHello (outside the function dostuff) even though it has the same name as an inner function?

```
var sayHello = function(){
    alert("Called from outside the function");
}
function doStuff(){
    sayHello();
    function sayHello(){
        alert("Called from inside the function. How can I call the sayHello function that is outside the scope of doStuff?");
    }
}
    doStuff();
​
```

In the Javascript code above, the function sayHello (which is the name of 2 functions) is invoked from inside the function, not outside.

Here it is on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5MSTU/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the outer function is global, you can target it as a member of the `window` object.

```
window.sayHello();
```

Otherwise, you'll need to use different names. JavaScript allows you to shadow variables, so an inner variable with the same name as an outer variable effectively disables access to the outer one.

Comment: If the scripting environment is node.js, does the same apply?

Comment: Or create a local variable that points to the outer function, and will act as an alias.

Comment: @AndersonGreen: Yes, except that the global variable object is referenced with the `global` identifier instead of `window`. `global.sayHello()`.

Comment: @Greg: But if it is already shadowed, there's no way to make the reference to the outer one with the local variable, unless the outer is defined in the global environment.

Answer (score -1):

--updated to remove the plain wrong code that was here--

You can alias it up front. But I don't know how useful this is.

```
var sayHello = function(){
    alert("Called from outside the function");
};

var aliasForSayHello = sayHello;

function doStuff() {
    function sayHello(){
        alert("Called from inside the function. How can I call the sayHello function that is outside the scope of doStuff?");
       aliasForSayHello();
    }       

    sayHello();

}

doStuff();

​
```

Comment: This calls the function inside the function, instead of the function outside the function. Here it is on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hTQLW/

Comment: Be sure to test your code. You're not creating the alias you're expecting. Also you're actually invoking the alias (which is to the inner function) before it is initialized, resulting in a *TypeError*

Comment: Here's how the interpreter sees your code: http://jsfiddle.net/S2qHv/ The declarations are effective rearranged to the order shown in this example.

Comment: Well pointed out. Sometimes no answer is better than a wrong one:(

Comment: We're all allowed one per day. ;)